# MongooseJS populate from other Schema

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

So I have two Models:

1. Tennis player (playerSchema)
2. List of matches (eventSchema)

First Model contains the following info:

```
const playerSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    matches: [{
        type: Object,
        ref: 'Events'    
    }]
})
```

Second Model contains the following:

```
const eventSchema = new Schema({
    event_title: String,
    matches: [{
        first_tennis_player_name: String,
        second_tennis_player_name: String,
        first_tennis_player_result: String,
        second_tennis_player_result: String
    }]
})
```

I want to populate `matches` with the data from second Model.
Pseudocode will be something like this:

`SELECT ALL TENNIS MATCHES WHERE FIRST_TENNIS_PLAYER_NAME  OR SECOND_TENNIS_PLAYER_NAME IS NAME`

Comment: What is stopping you to try to use mongoose populate? What have you tried?

Comment: I have edited my question. The edit is following: In playerSchema instead of matches type: Schema.Type.ObjectId I put type: Object. I am not sure I am doing this right. So in my players collection I have the name, age of the player. I want to generate the matches a tennis player played based on his name, not document ID. So I don't have document ID in neither one of the collections.

Comment: Try `match` while populating, https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions